# fabric.js on node.js failure applying filter

Tags: node.js, image, filter, fabricjs

Using 
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function(){

I get the following error if the image has a filter applied.

The error appears to be at/around ln 19484, i wrapped in a try catch block to and did console.log('element to draw' +elementToDraw.toString())  and console.log('ctx'+ctx.toString()) to see if the elements exist

```
      elementToDraw && ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
                                 x + imageMargins.marginX,
                                 y + imageMargins.marginY,
                                 imageMargins.width,
                                 imageMargins.height
                                );


    element to draw[object Image]
ctx[object CanvasRenderingContext2D]
TypeError: Image or Canvas expected
    at TypeError (native)
    at klass._render (fabric.js:19486:28)
    at klass.drawObject (fabric.js:13079:12)
    at klass.render (fabric.js:13016:14)
    at klass._renderObjects (fabric.js:7091:34)
    at klass.renderCanvas (fabric.js:7069:12)
    at klass.renderAll (fabric.js:9019:12)
    at fabric.js:11619:15
    at cbIfLoaded (fabric.js:11646:21)
    at klass.__setBgOverlay (fabric.js:11668:19)
json loaded
```

The fabric object is generated client side and then uploaded to the server where Fabric 1.7.22 is running under node . I tested with 1.5.0, 1.6.0, and 1.7.22 and all three show no difference.

The server is running node v6.12.3

When I run on the command line:

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/helloworld.png');

var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(400, 400);
try{
 var src = __dirname + '/client_318-CL-Tatnall_4x3_art.png';
 fs.readFile(src, function(erro, data) {
  if (erro) console.log(erro);  
  fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function (img) { 
   img.src = src;
   img.filters.push( new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia());
   img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
   
   img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";  
   img.width = canvas.width;
   img.height = canvas.height;
   console.log(img);

   try{
    img.applyFilters(); 
    canvas.add(img)

   } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
   }
  var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
  stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    out.write(chunk);
  });

  return;
  }, {crossOrigin: "anonymous"});
  return;
 });

} catch(err){
 console.log(err); 
}
```

I get the same error

Comment: please be sure jsdom and fabric are sharing the same node-canvas version, it should work  out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site https://www.bountysource.com/issues/6655913-node-canvas-image-or-canvas-expected-on-canvas-add-img:

It explains the problem and offers this as a solution:

```js
    var Canvas = require('canvas'); 
 var createCanvasForNode = fabric.createCanvasForNode;
 fabric.createCanvasForNode = function () {
    canvas = createCanvasForNode.apply(this, arguments);
   canvas.nodeCanvas = new Canvas(canvas.width, canvas.height);
   canvas.contextContainer = canvas.nodeCanvas.getContext('2d');
   return canvas;
 };
```

Adding this fixes the issue.